# "As" cast is unexpectedly failing

Tags: c#, casting, delegates

I'm doing a bunch of weird generic stuff which includes doing a lot of casts of delegate types,  and for the most part it's working perfectly.
However,  I'm running into cast failure that I can't find a reason for.
Here's my method, and following debug data.

```
    public static T GetInvokableDelegate<T>(string name) where T : class
    {
        return DelRegistry[name].GetSelectedMethod() as T;
        //DelRegistry[name].GetSelectedMethod() returns System.Object, 
        //which may be any flavor of Func<> or Action<>
    }
    //These two pairs represent the values from the Debug view, 
      //of T and GetSelectedMethod() respectively

    //This is when DelRegistry is returning the initial result from GetSelectedMethod():  This cast As T works fine.

    //System.Action<string,AIDECore.Controller>   
    //{Method = {Void HAL_TestMethod(System.String, AIDECore.Controller)}}    

    //This is after the second call,  GetSelectedMethod() is returning a different delegate, but with identical signature:  This one fails

    //System.Action<string,AIDECore.Controller>
    //{Method = {Void HAL_TestMethod(System.String, AIDECore.Controller)}}
```

Inspecting the values at runtime shows that they appear to be identical.  The specified cast works the first time,  fails the second time.
Of note: it's not the number of times it's been called causing it to fail.  In other test cases, I've added dozens of delegate versions to DelRegistry without problems.

My question is,  can you get error output as to WHY an "As" cast fails?  (Where failing means returning null)

**Cast exception data:**

```
[A]System.Action`2[System.String,AIDECore.Controller] cannot be cast to [B]System.Action`2[System.String,AIDECore.Controller].
Type A originates from 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.
Type B originates from 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.
```

So that basically says it can't cast.

For the record,  all versions returned from GetSelectedMethod() subsequent to the first, are from dynamically loaded Assemblies.

**So why has this casting worked fine hundreds of times until now?**

Comment: Well, what exactly is `T`, and what exactly is `DelRegistry[name].SelectedMethod()` returning ? Can you edit this to make it a runnable example that actually shows the problem?

Comment: As I said in the comment, T in this case was a System.Action.  I'll update the question

Comment: You could always try to replace the 'as' with a normal cast. This should give you an exception detailing why the cast was unsuccessful..

Comment: It was my understanding/assumption that casts of methods were done based on signature,  and for the large majority of using this specific method, it has worked fine.

Comment: You can try casting it and see the exception being thrown.

Comment: You still haven't indicated what T you are calling this with. *what is the T when it fails* ?

Comment: Marc,  as the code comment says rather loud and clear,  T is Action<string,AIDECore.Controller>

Comment: The code comment says no such thing (it talks of the object only); the exception data talks about `AIDECore.Controller`; is it possible you are loading 2 different versions of `AIDECore.Controller`? perhaps 2 versions of the dll (maybe from the GAC?)

Comment: That is exactly what I'm doing,  and I've been doing it successfully hundreds of times, but it's abruptly stopped casting, and I don't know why yet.

Comment: @Kal_Torak See my comment in my answer, which remains correct. It doesn't just stop casting, even if this is your perception. Note: two identical objects in two assemblies with different versions (assuming they are strong named) are seen as two distinct types by the .NET Framework. This is what is biting you, it has nothing to do with the casting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate assignments are based on signature, but casts are not. So if in your second case the T delegate type is different the cast "failing" is expected behavior.

To convert delegate types, use code like [this](http://code.logos.com/blog/2008/07/casting_delegates.html).

Edit: after reading your edit with the cast exception data, my bet is that your code somehow loads multiple different versions of the assembly holding the AIDECore.Controller type - check those types.

Comment: Yes, it does load different versions of the AIDECore.Controller type.  That is the whole point of my project.  It's worked perfectly until now,  with as many versions as I cared to load

Comment: This GetInvokeableDelegate is basically a layer of indirection allowing me to point delegates to whatever dynamically loaded assembly method I wish.

Comment: So your problem is actually not related to delegates but really to having different types (albeit with the same name) loaded. You need to make sure that this always loads the same type; have a look at [assembly redirection policies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx) for doing so. The invocation would also not work if you called `Invoke` on the delegate with late-binding - the parameter is of the wrong type. If it "used to work" then the code working must have been pointing to the same version of the AIDECore assembly.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that appears to be correct.  I'm still a bit hazy on whether you can actually use redirection policy to do runtime type substitution,  or is that only at startup?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if I need to redirect backwards or forwards.  New versions of the types contain methods which will accept an old version of the same type as argument.

Comment: How to redirect depends on the object compatibility but usually the new version is used instead of old versions. Maybe introducing a more stable interface may also be an option (if the "core" API is not set in stone).